# Create Excel XML files from Python

Tags: python, xml, excel

I need to create Excel XML files from Python.

The Excel XML format is fairly simple.  I looked at a a sample xml file saved from Excel 2003 and it is fairly simple.

I'm looking for a a Pythonic, ready made library to create such xml files instead of reinventing one.

Something that I can use as below:

```
book = Expy.Workbook()
s1 = book.add_sheet()
s1[0, 2] = "A3"
s1[0, 0] = 12
s1[0, 9] = Expy.Formula("=Sum(A1:A3)")

book.write("excelfile.xml")
```

Anybody know of something like that?

xlwt seems outdated, supporting python 2.x only, and seems to write xls files, not xml.

Comment: Be aware that the XML generated by Excel 2003 is totally different from the Open XML (xlsx) files from Excel 2007/2010

Answer (score 3):

give [pythonOffice](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pythonoffice/) a try

Comment: Looks promising. But seems a bit outdated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows with Excel installed, you could look into Excel Automation.

```
from win32com import client
excel_app = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# check VBA documentation on automating excel...
```

Comment: Good idea, but I may not have Excel installed.

Answer (score 1):

xlwt will write Excel files from python, but I'm not sure if it handles the newer XML file formats.
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt